# Get original e-mail sender server in Python

Tags: python, email, imap

With many e-mail services, you can get tricked into believing an e-mail has been sent from a different address.

Using `smtplib` in Python, you can easily do the trick by manipulating the `From` argument.

`gmail` is not prone to that as they print the `via` argument which shows the *original* server.

However, what I cannot find anywhere is *how do you retrieve the original (not manipulated) server name* in Python, the same as `gmail` does with their `via` functionality?

I've tried the `imaplib` and `email` libraries, but there I can only access the already manipulated sender.

Any ideas? Is that solely linked to the configuration of a particular provider (e.g. `Google`, `Outlook`, `hotmail`, etc.), or can something be done regardless of that?

Here is part of the code I'm currently using (no success):

```
import imaplib
import email

obj = imaplib.IMAP4('imap', portn)
obj.login('username', 'password')

obj.select('INBOX')

uidl_list = [68720]

resp, data = obj.uid('FETCH', ','.join(map(str, uidl_list)) , '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (From Subject)] RFC822.SIZE)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard about the `via` field. It is related to this particular provider.

You may check the `Received` headers of the mail to know what SMTP servers the message went through. Assuming those are not fake and were not modified along the way (i.e. assuming you trust the servers), they should point you to the SMTP server the user connected to to send the message.

Example:

```
Received: from mail-ot1-x333.google.com (mail-ot1-x333.google.com [IPv6:2617:f8c0:4864:20::331])
 by smtp.domain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 6C488D0F8
 for <user@domain.tld>; Mon, 19 Nov 2018 21:13:54 +0100 (CET)
Received: by mail-ot1-x333.google.com with SMTP id w25so38121669otm.11
        for <user@domain.tld>; Mon, 19 Nov 2018 12:13:54 -0800 (PST)
```

A user connected to `mail-ot1-x333.google.com`, posted a message for `user@domain.tld`. The SMTP server added the `Received` header that appears at the bottom. Then, it sent the message to `domain.tld`, and Postfix server at `domain.tld` added the header that appears on top.

From [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.4), the `Received` headers are always added on top.

```
An Internet mail program MUST NOT change or delete a Received: line
that was previously added to the message header section.  SMTP
servers MUST prepend Received lines to messages; they MUST NOT change
the order of existing lines or insert Received lines in any other
location.
```

The last one should always be the one indicating the SMTP server the user connected to.

Note that there are good reasons to have a `From` domain that does not match the SMTP server used for sending the message.:

- ISP forces users to use their own SMTP server
- Using several email accounts with a mail client that only offers a songle SMTP configuration

Comment: Perfect - I didn't know about the Received! I know there may be use cases, but in my situation these should be filtered out, I'll just need some parsing and that's it.

Comment: However, just out of curiosity - are there any alternatives when SMTP servers are fake?

Comment: Well, if you can't trust __all__ of the SMTP servers on the chain, you can only assume all headers may be forged.